# How to get android device properties

Tags: android

how can i get android device's platformId,deviceUser,deviceName,deviceModel, deviceOperatingSystem,deviceOSVersion from my program.

Edit: i have already used that Build class and got device id, model and user but for my requirement i need device OS, OS version and platform id.so how can i get them??

thanks
venu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extending to what CommonsWare suggested, I think here's what you need:

[Build.VERSION_CODES](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html): Enumeration of the currently known SDK version codes. These are the values that can be found in SDK. Version numbers increment monotonically with each official platform release.

1. DONUT : Constant Value: 4 (0x00000004)
2. ECLAIR : Constant Value: 5 (0x00000005)
3. ECLAIR_0_1 : Constant Value: 6 (0x00000006)
4. ECLAIR_MR1 : Constant Value: 7 (0x00000007)
5. FROYO : Constant Value: 8 (0x00000008)
6. GINGERBREAD : Constant Value: 9 (0x00000009)

[Build class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html): Information about the current build, extracted from system properties.
Build.MODEL
Build.PRODUCT

[Build.VERSION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html): 
Various version strings.
Build.VERSION.RELEASE
Build.VERSION.SDK_INT

Comment: thanks to both @CommonsWare and @TheCottonSilk, i got the solution from Build class.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`android.os.Build`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html).

Comment: thank u @CommonsWare, can u please have a look at my edit section??

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example:

```
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
buf.append("VERSION.RELEASE {"+Build.VERSION.RELEASE+"}");
buf.append("\nVERSION.INCREMENTAL {"+Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL+"}");
buf.append("\nVERSION.SDK_INT {"+Build.VERSION.SDK_INT+"}");
buf.append("\nFINGERPRINT {"+Build.FINGERPRINT+"}");
buf.append("\nBOARD {"+Build.BOARD+"}");
buf.append("\nBRAND {"+Build.BRAND+"}");
buf.append("\nDEVICE {"+Build.DEVICE+"}");
buf.append("\nMANUFACTURER {"+Build.MANUFACTURER+"}");
buf.append("\nMODEL {"+Build.MODEL+"}");
```

Complete android.os.Build documentation is at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html

Note that `VERSION.SDK` is marked as deprecated, so `VERSION.SDK_INT` was used instead.