# Android, How can I extract mobile information?

Tags: android

I want to collect some information of mobile phone such as phone number, which brand it is, model of the device and product name.

I know how to extract phone number but i don't know the rest. if it's possible guide me please.

[EDITED]
Thank you dear friends, I did what you suggested me and now every thing is ok in Emulator and I have result. But the problem is when I want to run it on My phones (Galaxy S and Galaxy S2) both of them crash. What is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Check this Thread already answered [Device Information][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810529/how-to-get-android-device-properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer andorid.os.Build class at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use

[android.os.Build](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html)