# Android device properties are got at two levels one at android shell level and another at application level differently

Tags: java, android

At shell level I use:

```
adb shell getprop
```

to get properties
If I have to get property information at application level which command am I supposed to use.
I tried

```
String productname = System.getProperty("ro.product.name")
```

and getting no error but It is not returning correct value what could be the reason.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get android device properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810529/how-to-get-android-device-properties)

Comment: You are right but this question helps newcomers like me to understand that getprop has to be used at device level and  android.os.Build.HARDWARE at application level.

Comment: I have another command which can be useful for developer if you don't want to bother the build, mPropertyService.get("ro.hardware", "") which returns a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String deviceName = android.os.Build.MODEL;
String deviceMan = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
```

Please refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html) for more

Comment: accessing from adb is a different thing. in java you are provided with Build class from android sdk

Comment: I want to get ro.hardware information of an android device, how to get it at application level.

Comment: I used android.os.Build.HARDWARE and got the result thank you Sahil